# How filter email where FlagRequest=empty?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to filter emails in a subfolder.
Criterion: FlagRequest
Condition: "" '' Empty

I have the following attempts:

```vb
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] = ''"
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] ="""
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] =' '"
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] =''"
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] =" & Chr (34) & Chr (34) & "

Dim allCount As Integer: allCount = 0
Dim restCounter As Integer: restCounter = 0
allCount = oFolder.Items.count
restCounter = oFolder.Items.Restrict (myRestrict) .count
```

Hits: 0

If I go to:

```
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] <> '" & "Follow up" & "'"
```

I get the searched one, but also more.

Answer (score 0):

When filtering an empty string with a DASL query, you can use the `Is Null` keyword. `Is Null` operations are useful to determine if a string property is empty or if a date property has been set. For more information, see [Filtering Items Using Query Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-query-keywords).

```
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] Is Null"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict to items where there is no entry with

```
myRestrict = "[FlagRequest] = """""
```